# TRIM function causing issue in outout running on CDH3

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Following code causing issue in CDH3 cluster:

```
-- Case 1
A = FILTER XYZ BY (TRIM(var1) != 'U') AND (TRIM(var2) == 'N') AND (var3) == 'Y');
```

If I am executing following code then getting different results (Please notice I have removed `TRIM` in below code):

```
-- Case 2
A = FILTER XYZ BY (var1 != 'U' AND var2 == 'N' AND var3 == 'Y');
```

If I am executing following code getting the same results as that of `Case 2` (Please notice I have removed first `TRIM` from `NOT` operator):

```
-- Case 3
A = FILTER XYZ BY (var1 != 'U' AND (TRIM(var2) == 'N') AND (TRIM(var3) == 'Y');
```

If am executing all conditions sequentially in three different filter with `TRIM` or without `TRIM` getting the same results as that of `Case 2` and `Case 3`:

```
-- Case 4
A = FILTER XYZ BY (TRIM(var1) != 'U');
B = FILTER A BY (TRIM(var2) == 'N');
C = FILTER B BY (TRIM(var3) == 'Y');
STORE C;

-- Case 5
A = FILTER XYZ BY var1 != 'U';
B = FILTER A BY var2 == 'N';
C = FILTER B BY var3 == 'Y';
STORE C;
```

Did any one encounter problem using `TRIM` with `NOT` operator along with LOGICAL operator on CDH3 running with `PIG 0.8`?

I'm getting same results in CDH4 whatever cases I ran running with default `PIG 0.11`.

Comment: Is `(var3) == 'Y')` a typo? Shouldn't it be `(var3 == 'Y')`.